# FFTW: Logical array size in r2r transform?

Tags: dct

I'm taking a multidimensional discrete cosine transform (`FFTW_REDFT11`) in FFTW, and am unsure how to compute the scaling factor.  According to the [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html), taking the forward and reverse transforms results in the original image multiplied by a scaling factor:

> [C]omputing a transform followed by its inverse yields the original
>   array scaled by N, where N is the logical DFT size. For REDFT00,
>   N=2(n-1); for RODFT00, N=2(n+1); otherwise, N=2n.

The documentation also defines logical arrays for 1D transforms:

> [I]f you specify a size-5 REDFT00 (DCT-I) of the data abcde, it
>   corresponds to the DFT of the logical even array abcdedcb of size 8. A
>   size-4 REDFT10 (DCT-II) of the data abcd corresponds to the size-8
>   logical DFT of the even array abcddcba, shifted by half a sample.

I'm not sure what `n` is in a multidimensional transform.  Say I have a 10x10 matrix.  Is n twice the total number of pixels (200)?  Or is it the number of pixels in the image if it were reflected in all dimensions (400)?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  The distinction must be made between the physical size of your array, n (generally $n_0 × n_1 × n_2 × … × n_{d-1}$ except for in-place R2C transforms), and the logical size, N.  For a 10x10 matrix, the physical size is n=10*10=100, so the logical size for this particular transform is N=2n=200,  the scaling factor for the unnormalized transform-then-inverse result.

They talk a little more about that [here in the Real even/odd FFTW3 docs](http://www.fftw.org/doc/1d-Real_002deven-DFTs-_0028DCTs_0029.html#g_t1d-Real_002deven-DFTs-_0028DCTs_0029), although they don't give much more info than the link you provided.

It's always a good idea to test with a problem that you already know the answer to,